# why I search Milvus return `The vector dimension must be equal to the collection dimension`?

Tags: java, helper, dimension, milliseconds, sa

great guys.I have one problem to ask all of you for help!
Yesterday,I have a task that was I need to search Milvus.
The Milvus API in my application is already have.I just need to get the `client` and send request!
But there is a wild question cause I operation in local and it return this  `The vector dimension must be equal to the collection dimension` But I operation in test environmnrt it is `SUCCESS`!
I am pretty sure that the both environment have same code!  So, I can't understand what the issue is???

Comment: I found the answer:
   the error is the data I used to test's size is 640 but the milvus server's dimension is 512

Comment: If you have the answer already, then you can answer your own question, please. Thereby others who are having the same issue can know it, too.